# Sync two different Ubuntu computers in U14.04

Tags: 14.04, sync

I have one laptop and one desktop PC with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit.
I want to synchronize the Home/Documents folder in a fashion similar as Dropbox. 
I am not a power user, is there any really easy way to that? I found other solutions but all need to have the PC always open.

Thanks,

Comment: I use Unison over ssh or via a USB hard disk. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/633673/syncronizing-with-unison-on-ubuntu   and/or http://askubuntu.com/questions/493063/unison-automatically-sync-computers