# sync two folders on two separate ext HDD

Tags: command-line, bash, sync

I have folder-A on an ext HDD lets say HDD-A, and folder-B in ext HDD-B.

Is there a way to sync both folders automatically? either real-time or once a day at least

Comment: The tool you are looking for might be `rsync`.

Comment: any GUI for rsync?

Comment: Why would you need a GUI is your requirement is to sync "...either in real-time or once a day at least..."?

Comment: just curious. Is there  way to rsync automatically without having to use the CLI everyday to sync folders?

Comment: To sync automatically (that is, without using either GUI or CLI everyday), put your `rsync` command in `crontab`.

Comment: i just tried rsync and it seems that it sync dir-a with dir-b, however if i add a file to dir-b the dir-a is not updated.  Is there a way to sync both?

Comment: Yes, use `rsync` twice.

Answer (score 3):

I use [`rsync` [image: Install rsync]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/rsync) for tasks like that:

```
rsync -a "/path/to/hdd1/dir-a" "/path/to/hdd2/dir-b"
```

You can [add a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368/507051) to schedule the task, I recommend redirecting `rsync`’s output to a log file. E.g. to run it every 10 minutes and save the output in `~/logs/rsync.log`:

```
*/10 * * * * rsync -a "/path/to/hdd1/dir-a" "/path/to/hdd2/dir-b" >~/logs/rsync.log
```

If you prefer a GUI you can use [`grsync` [image: Install grsync]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/grsync):

[image: grsync]

When you configured it to your needs, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to display the correspondent command line.

Answer (score 3):

## Unison

You can use [unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to keep two paths synchronised bi-directionally. The good thing about using unison, as compared to simpler programs like rsync, is that it has built-in conflict resolution handling. For instance, if in `pathA/foo.txt` and `pathB/foo.txt` have both changed, the program needs to know which file you want.

Basic usage for unison is:

```
$ unison -auto path/to/A path/to/B
```

then it will try to keep the structures below `path/to/A` and `path/to/B` in sync. You can also add the `-batch` flag to make it work non-interactively, although conflicts will not get resolved this way.

Unison will save a state for each sync pair, so it will remember your preferences for conflict resolution. There are quite some options available for different use cases.

It is available in Ubuntu as package `unison`. A GUI version is also available as `unison-gtk`.

**Warning** As with all automatic synchronisation solutions, please first make yourself familiar with the program in a test environment. Also read the documentation thoroughly. It is easy to mess up and end up overwriting the wrong files.

Extended manual:

- https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html

Related:

- [syncronizing with unison on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633673/syncronizing-with-unison-on-ubuntu)
- [Unison - Automatically Sync Computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493063/unison-automatically-sync-computers)

Comment: +1 – I never heard of `unison` before even though it has an [extensive (German) wiki.ubuntuusers.de article](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Unison/) which covers automatisation quite well.

Comment: It is rather complex, but for real two-way sync with conflict resolution I don't know anything better.

Comment: +1. I use Unison and can recommend it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/). It works fast and great.

[image: FreeFileSync on Ubuntu]

I'm using it for synchronization between HDDs, USB-flashes, SSHFS, Samba share and/or local folder.

Also it has real-time sync mode (named as [RealTimeSync](https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=realtimesync)).

You can install as FlatPak:

```
sudo apt-get install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.freefilesync.FreeFileSync
```

---

It works great in conjunction with Meld (`sudo apt-get install meld`).
You need to open FreeFileSync options (*Tools→Options*) and then add the following to the first line:

```
 |        Description       |             Command line            |
 |  Compare files in Meld   |  meld "%item_path%" "%item_path2%"  |
```

as shown on screenshot:

[image: FreeFileSync Tools→Options]

Comment: I like it, but the icons are text are really large on my system. I wish I could get from my screen,