# How do you compare two root filesystems - but ignore mount points?

Tags: mount, filesystem, root, diff

I have rootfs `/` but within that I have `/mnt/another_rootfs` which contains a second mounted rootfs.

I want to compare the files in them... but when I do somthng like: `diff -r / /mnt/another_rootfs` I start to get all the mount points being compared (which I am not so interested in) but also the `/` rootfs will also contain the second mounted `/mnt/another_rootfs` ... that is causing issues as well.

So I really just want to diff the files that are actually mounted on `/` vs the files mounted on `/mnt/another_rootfs` and not recurse into other mounts.

Is that possible?

Comment: I can recommend to use [FreeFileSync](http://freefilesync.org/) - see [this answer for screenshot](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040956/66509) in conjunction with Meld.

Comment: @N0rbert I don't see how (in the answer) this gets around the mount point issue?

Comment: You can set ignore filters in FFS if you want. Also you can ignore or include symlinks.

Comment: ah... ok. Its a bit manual though for me. There are many mount points : (... but I suppose it could be done - thanks : )

Comment: Probably most easy way is to mount both `/`-filesystems under it's own mount-points in a live-session and compare the mount-points.

Answer (score 1):

A command line solution is easy, when you reverse the question to "I want to `diff /mnt/another_rootfs /`":

```
find /mnt/another_rootfs -xdev -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r $HOME/bin/diffwithslash
```

Where `$HOME/bin/diffwithslash` is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
   afile="$1"
   shift
   bfile="${afile#/mnt/another_rootfs}"
   if [[ -f "$afile" ]] && [[ -f "$bfile" ]] ; then
       diff "$bfile" "$afile"
   fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: This would work : ) - but its more a script solution, I didn't really want to write a script if I could avoid it :o

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the partition which holds the `/`-file-system of the currently booted installation to a second mount-point and compare this mount-point with the mount-point of the other `/`-file-system.

Use `lsblk -f` to check which partition is mounted at `/`.

Then mount the partition with

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdXY /mnt (replace XY with the found value)
```

Compare `/mnt` with the the folder which is the mount-point of the other `/`-file-system.

Unmount with `sudo umount /mnt`

Comment: That helps - but the sub-mount points will still be there (like /proc and /sys etc...) is there a way to not recurse into these?

Comment: The mount-points /`proc` and `/sys` are empty folders on the disk. They are only populated in a running system. E.g the `procfs` provided by the kernel will be mounted to `/proc`.